# Motivation of Fourier Coefficents

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

What motivates the definition of the definition of the Fourier coefficients? I understand that one would try to find Fourier coefficients, but not why they are defined the way they are.

Comment: If you have an orthonormal basis $(e_i)_i$ and want to write $a$ in this basis, then $a = \sum_{i} a_i e_i$ with $a_i = \langle a, e_i\rangle$ (it's easy to see by taking the dot product with $e_i$ of the LHS and RHS). Now, take the relevant inner product for the Fourier transform, and the right basis, you'll get the definition.

Comment: @Clement This assumes such an inner product. Why would guess such an inner product?

Comment: Being in a vector space endowed with an inner product is at the basis of the Fourier transform (the basis is *orthogonal*, etc.)

Comment: Yes, but from my understanding, the inner product that is used is used because it was what picked out the Fourier coefficients, but why would one first come to trying to pick out the Fourier coefficients this way?

Comment: No. You want a specific baais (trigonometric functions). To make it orthogonal, you get a given inner product. This in turn leads to the definition of the coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

The original motivation came from solving the problem of a vibrating string stretched between fixed endpoints, which arose in the mid to late 1700s. In the process of studying this equation, Mathematicians discovered standing wave solutions vibrating at frequencies that were integer multiples of a base frequency. (This is origin of harmonic analysis.) In order to solve a general problem with a more general initial displacement of the string using sums of such standing wave solutions, it became necessary to determine the coefficients for those solutions in a general sum

Clairaut and Euler discovered a way to isolate the coefficients through the amazing discovery of the orthogonality conditions for trigonometric functions. Most Mathematicians at the time thought that such a general expansion of initial displacement of the string into trigonometric functions would not be possible. So, there was a consensus that this represented a restriction on the problems that could solved, and not a way to find general solution of the vibrating string problem.

Fourier became convinced that a general "mechanical" function representing the initial position of the string would have to be expandable in such a way. Because of the work of Fourier in this direction, the coefficients were named after Fourier, even though Fourier did not discover them. Fourier extensively studied trigonometric expansions.

Comment: What did they do to isolate the coefficients?

Comment: They used the interesting observation that the integral over $[0,2\pi]$ of the product of any two different functions in the Fourier basis was $0$. So, if $f=a_0 + a_1\cos(nx)+b_1\sin(nx)+a_2\cos(2nx)+b_2\sin(2nx)+\cdots$, then you could multiply both sides by one of the trig functions and integrate in order to isolate one coefficient at a time.